# How to print the datagridview results in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, printing

I have a datagridview on a form and a print button below it...i want that when i click the print button the print dialog should appear and the datagrid results should be printed...How can it be done??Can anyone tell me??

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="JavaScript:window.print();">Print this page</a>
```

You might also want to investigate using separate stylesheets for printing and screen by using [the `media` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp).  This will provide better printing results.